# Game Center not showing in iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I used this tutorial to access GameCenter.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-12
I am able to lo in the game center but then if I want to  use this code:

```
 SFAppDelegate * delegate = (SFAppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;                
    [[GCHelper sharedInstance] findMatchWithMinPlayers:2 maxPlayers:2 viewController:self delegate:self];
```

This code should work, but if I call i it only shows black screen with blue toolbar in above. 
the "self" in here is UIViewController and this controller implements the GCHelper delegate methods.

the method find ... looks like this:

```
- (void)findMatchWithMinPlayers:(int)minPlayers maxPlayers:(int)maxPlayers viewController:(UIViewController *)viewController delegate:(id<GCHelperDelegate>)theDelegate {

    if (!gameCenterAvailable) return;

    matchStarted = NO;
    self.match = nil;
    self.presentingViewController = viewController; // ?
    delegate = theDelegate;               
    [presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];


    if (pendingInvite != nil) 
    {   
        [presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithInvite:pendingInvite] autorelease];
        mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;
        [presentingViewController presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:YES];

        self.pendingInvite = nil;
        self.pendingPlayersToInvite = nil;
    }
    else 
    {   
        [presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        GKMatchRequest *request = [[[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] autorelease]; 
        request.minPlayers = minPlayers;     
        request.maxPlayers = maxPlayers;
        request.playersToInvite = pendingPlayersToInvite;

        GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request] autorelease];    
        mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;

        [presentingViewController presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:YES];

        self.pendingInvite = nil;
        self.pendingPlayersToInvite = nil;
    }
}
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong.... 
Thanks for any suggestions for correction. 
:)